# Unwanted horizontal scroll in android app created with Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a problem with one of screens of my Ionic app. here is the template:

```
<ion-content scroll="false" ng-controller="OptionsCtrl">
  <div class="image-thumbnail_options">
    <img ng-src="{{data.imageData}}"/>
  </div>
  <div class="list raleway-medium format-radio_options">
    <div>
      <p class="primary-color">Select output file format</p>
    </div>
    <ion-radio ng-repeat="item in outputFormatList"
               ng-value="item.value"
               ng-model="data.outputFormat">
      {{ item.text }}
    </ion-radio>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons-group_options">
    <button class="button button-flat" ng-click="show()">
      <i class="raleway-bold primary-color icon-left ion-checkmark-circled"> CONTINUE</i>
    </button>
    <button class="button button-flat" ui-sref="main">
      <i class="raleway-bold primary-color icon-left ion-android-cancel"> CANCEL</i>
    </button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

The problem is, that as the page loads, with the image, it is correctly centered and covers full size, but I can see, that I can horizontally scroll it what results in this:
[wtf-scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3T4qS.png)
I have no clue, why it behaves like that so I would really appreciate any help or advice.
From scss:

```
.image-thumbnail_options {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33%;
    img {
      padding: $options_image-padding;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

I posted this question also on Ionic's forums, but i didn't get any response in meantime. I think it may be a bug with Android API 19(4.4 Kitkat) WebView or with ionic as I am not able to reproduce this on the Lollipop, nor on the IOS.